# Replace the value of a specific element that is either divisible by 2, 3, or 2 and 3 PHP

Tags: php, for-loop

I don't know how to change the value of an element if it is divisible by 2, 3, or 2 and 3. i wanted to output 2 if it is divisible by 2. 3 if it is divisible by 3. and 1 if it is divisible by 2 and 3.

```
<?php

for ( $i = 1 ; $i <= 50 ; $i++ ){

        if( $i % 3 == 0 && $i % 2 == 0 ){               
            echo "1 = ";
        }

        else if( $i % 2 == 0){
            echo "2 = ";
        }
        else if( $i % 3 == 0){
            echo "3 = ";
        }
            echo $i.', ';

}
?>
```

this is my output. I don't want to print the numbers which are divisible by 2, 3, and 2 and 3.

```
1, 2 = 2, 3 = 3, 2 = 4, 5, 1 = 6, 7, 2 = 8, 3 = 9, 2 = 10, 11, 1 = 12, 13, 2 = 14, 3 = 15, 2 = 16, 17, 1 = 18, 19, 2 = 20, 3 = 21, 2 = 22, 23, 1 = 24, 25, 2 = 26, 3 = 27, 2 = 28, 29, 1 = 30, 31, 2 = 32, 3 = 33, 2 = 34, 35, 1 = 36, 37, 2 = 38, 3 = 39, 2 = 40, 41, 1 = 42, 43, 2 = 44, 3 = 45, 2 = 46, 47, 1 = 48, 49, 2 = 50,
```

i wanted to output it like this one below!

1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 1, 7, 2, 3, 2, 11, 1, 13, 2, 3, 2, 17, 1, 19, 2, 3, 2, 23, 1, 25, 2, 3, 2, 29, 1, 31, 2, 3, 2, 35, 1, 37, 2, 3, 2, 41, 1, 43, 2, 3, 2, 47, 1, 49, 2,

Comment: seems like you don't need a regex for this.

Comment: What about  :for ( $i = 1 ; $i <= 50 ; $i++ ){if(! ($i % 3 == 0 || $i % 2 == 0) ){ echo $i.', ';}}
-> print only number not divisible by 2, 3 or both.

Comment: How come `5`, `7` divisible by `2` or `3`??

Comment: Thank you sir Guilhem Hoffman!

Comment: your output do not correspond exactly to your description : " I don't want to print the numbers which are divisible by 2, 3, and 2 and 3." either you donot want them or you want to replace them by the divisor, please clarify

Answer (score 1):

Well, then you shouldn't print them always.

```
for ( $i = 1 ; $i <= 50 ; $i++ ) {
    if( $i % 3 == 0 && $i % 2 == 0 ){               
        echo "1, ";
    } else if( $i % 2 == 0){
        echo "2, ";
    } else if( $i % 3 == 0){
        echo "3, ";
    } else {
        echo $i.', ';
    }
}
```